# Pass variables in function to data.table for lm()

Tags: r, function, data.table, lm

I want to create a function to run lm() on all data.table columns but specify the dependent (x) and by columns. The data.table, x, and by arguments are passed to the function.

I am using David Arenburg's data.table [solution][1] with lapply() to calculate lm() and attempting to pass variables through the function with deparse() and substitute() without success.

Below is a MWE of the desired data.table result and my function attempt, trying to pass arguments as variables and not quoted character strings.

I believe this involves non-standard evaluation (I did read NSE in Advanced R but my understanding is not quite there).

Any help is appreciated thanks!

```r
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

# Sample dataset
data1 <- data.table(colA = 1:10,
                    colB = runif(10),
                    colC = runif(10),
                    colD = rep(c("apples", "bananas"),5))

# Desired functionality with .SDcols and by
works <- data1[, .(lm_results = lapply(.SD, function(x) {
  lm_summary = summary(lm(colA ~ x))})),
  .SDcols = -c("colA"),
  by = .(colD)]


# attempted function
fun1 <- function(dt, y, by_col) {

  x <- dt[, .(lm_results = lapply(.SD, function(x) {
    summary(lm(substitute(y) ~ x))})),
    .SDcols = -c(deparse(substitute(y)),),
    by = .(substitute(by_col))]

  return(x)
}

fails <- fun1(data1, colA, colD)
#> Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , .(lm_results = lapply(.SD, function(x) {: column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type symbol. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think `.()` works magic more arcane than usual. `by` can accept a string, so perhaps try `by = deparse(substitute(by_col))`

Comment: Hmm, no luck there. There's a nice error message which suggests using `by = eval(deparse(substitute()))`, but that's not working for me either.

Comment: Well, bad news is if you change to `by = by_col` and use a quoted column name, which should work, there's an error in another piece: `Error in c(deparse(substitute(y)), ) : argument 2 is empty`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried several different approaches including passing the formula argument to `lm` as a string, and different variations of NSE for the passed variable. In the function if you remove the `by` and change `lm(substitute(y) ~ x)` to `lm(colA ~ x)` it works, so there's a starting point I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `quote` and `substitute` from [Pass variable name as argument inside data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379368/pass-variable-name-as-argument-inside-data-table/57379693#57379693) with tweaks to your `lm` formula and `.SDcols`:

```
fun1 <- function(dt, y, by_col) {
    expr <- quote(dt[, 
        .(lm_results=lapply(.SD, function(x) summary(lm(Y ~ x)))),
        .SDcols=sdcols,
        by=byexpr])
    eval(do.call(substitute, list(expr, 
        list(sdcols=substitute(!y), Y=as.name(y), byexpr=substitute(by_col)))))
}

fun1(data1, "colA", colD)
```

The uncool thing is that `colA` needs to be passed in as a string.

output:

```
      colD   lm_results
1:  apples <summary.lm>
2:  apples <summary.lm>
3: bananas <summary.lm>
4: bananas <summary.lm>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Why is `quote` used instead of `substitute` to create `expr`? And I'm not quite clear on the `eval` part either. I read `quote` and `eval` are opposites where they peel off each others layers. So `eval` evaluates `do.call` which calls `substitute` as the function, and you have passed a list with `expr` and then a second list with the variables inside `expr`. How does it know to pass the `list(sdcols=substitue(!y)....` to `list(expr, ...)` and how are those passed as multiple arguments to `substitute`? I'm sorry for these basic questions...thank you!